# Calculate raster with each cell equals the mean of all adjacent cells

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am working on an ecological problem, involving species distribution models. I have a raster which is essentially a landscape of probabilities of presence per cell, so to speak. I want to calculate a new raster, based on the old one, where each cell is equal to the mean of itself and all 8 adjacent cells. This is not the same as aggregating the cells by mean, which results in the border between the newly aggregated cells being calculated incorrectly.

I can do this with the bit of code provided, but the raster I am working with is way, way too big to run this calculation, as it uses too much memory. If I subdivide the raster, it will still take days to do. Does anyone have a more efficient way of calculating this? I have created a small version of the raster as an example, albeit somewhat clumsily:

```
require(raster)

## create raster called "ras" rather clumsily
## create raster called "ras" rather clumsily
# (UTM coordinates and a probability value for each cell, not really 
# important)
s.x = seq(249990, by = 30, length.out = 20)
s.y = seq(6189390, by = 30, length.out = 20)

x.l = lapply(1:20, function(x){
  rep(s.x[x], 20)
})

x.l2 = as.vector(c(x.l[[1]], x.l[[2]], x.l[[3]], x.l[[4]], x.l[[5]], 
x.l[[6]], x.l[[7]], x.l[[8]], x.l[[9]], x.l[[10]],
  x.l[[11]], x.l[[12]], x.l[[13]], x.l[[14]], x.l[[15]], 
x.l[[16]],x.l[[17]], x.l[[18]], x.l[[19]], x.l[[20]])) 

df = as.data.frame(cbind(x.l2, rep(s.y, 20), rnorm(20*20, 0.5, 0.2)))

colnames(df) = c("x", "y", "P")

coordinates(df) <- ~ x + y
gridded(df) <- TRUE
ras = raster(df)

# for each cell, make a vector of the values at 
# the cell and all <=8 adjacent cells:
vl = lapply(1:length(ras), function(x){
  extract(ras, 
          (c(x,(adjacent(ras, x, directions=8, pairs=F, sorted=F)))))
})

# find the mean for each cell
vm = sapply(1:length(ras), function(x){
  as.vector(mean(vl[[x]], na.rm = T))
})

# create raster template
templ = ras/ras

# multiply into template for new raster
ras = vm*templ
```

Comment: Check [`raster::focal`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-4/topics/focal), as described e.g. here: [Smoothing a 2D matrix with rollmean, filter, rollapply or other R facilities by moving average sliding window method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626361/1851712)

Comment: Thank you! With minor modifications, this was exactly what I needed.